# problem with adding UIActivityIndicator to the view !

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to add a UIActivityIndicator to my custom view (programmatically). I am using the following code. But I dont see anything on the screen. Any idea why ?

Thanks.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator=[[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 395, 200, 200)] autorelease];
[activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityIndicator.center=self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

Comment: Can you try the activity style as gray (so that is clear, in case if your background is white too) and finally make the activity indicator start animating?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`UIActivityIndicator` has its `hidesWhenStopped` property equal to `YES` by default - that is it is hidden if you do not start animating it. So to make it appear on the screen try one of the following (whichever is more suitable for you):

1. set `hidesWhenStopped` property to `NO`
2. start animating it (using `-startAnimating` method)
3. comment "activityIndicator.center=self.view.center;"

Answer (score 2):

Another reason is maybe because you're not set the activity indicator position correctly. From what I see, you want to place the activity indicator to the center of it's parent view. But to do that, you must do something like activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0);

Comment: thanks for the help, i have already figured it out, but thanks anyways :)